# Confused, Looping over nested Object and doing specific calculations

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, ecmascript-6

I am stuck! I have the following code:

```
const hours = [
    {
        "workHour" : "8",
        "Item name 1" : 120,
        "Item name 2" : 149,
        "Item name 3" : 137
    },
    {
        "workHour" : "9",
        "Item name 1" : 134,
        "Item name 2" : 119,
        "Item name 3" : 144
    },
    {
        "workHour" : "10",
        "Item name 1" : 60,
        "Item name 2" : 86,
        "Item name 3" : 83
    },
];

const records = [
   { date: new Date(), statistics: hours },
   { date: new Date(), statistics: hours },
   { date: new Date(), statistics: hours },
];

const result = {};
result.chart = [];

records.forEach((record) => {
   const items = [];
   record.statistics.forEach((hour) => {
      for (let key in hour) {
         if (key !== 'workHour') {
           items.push({
              key: hour[key]
           })
         }
      }
   });
   result.chart.push({
      date: record.date,
      items
   });
});

console.log(result);
```

What I'm trying to do is loop over each item in the records array, then loop over the hours of each record, sum together all values of every item, like calculating the total from all of the hours, the result I am tryin to get is:

```
array = [
  { 
    date: //record date,
    "Item name 1" : 314,
    "Item name 2" : 354,
    "Item name 3" : 364
  },
  { 
    date: //record date,
    "Item name 1" : 314,
    "Item name 2" : 354,
    "Item name 3" : 364
  },
  { 
    date: //record date,
    "Item name 1" : 314,
    "Item name 2" : 354,
    "Item name 3" : 364
  }
];
```

Working example when the hours item keys are known:

```
const hours = [
{
    "workHour" : "8",
    "Item name 1" : 120,
    "Item name 2" : 149,
    "Item name 3" : 137
},
{
    "workHour" : "9",
    "Item name 1" : 134,
    "Item name 2" : 119,
    "Item name 3" : 144
},
{
    "workHour" : "10",
    "Item name 1" : 60,
    "Item name 2" : 86,
    "Item name 3" : 83
},
```

];

```
const records = [
   { date: new Date(), statistics: hours },
   { date: new Date(), statistics: hours },
   { date: new Date(), statistics: hours },
];

const result = {};
result.records = [];

const calculate = (profits, key) =>
  profits
  .filter(profit => profit !== null)
  .reduce((prevVal, profitVal) => prevVal + profitVal[key], 0) || 0;

records.forEach((record) => {
   const items = [];
   const { statistics } = record;
   result.records.push({
      date: record.date,
      'Item name 1': calculate(statistics, 'Item name 1'),
      'Item name 2': calculate(statistics, 'Item name 2'),
      'Item name 3': calculate(statistics, 'Item name 3'),
   });
});

console.log(result);
```

Prints:

```
records = [


{
      'Item name 1': 314,
      'Item name 2': 354,
      'Item name 3': 364,
   },
   {
      'Item name 1': 314,
      'Item name 2': 354,
      'Item name 3': 364,
   },
   {
      'Item name 1': 314,
      'Item name 2': 354,
      'Item name 3': 364,
   },
]
```

Comment: You are trying to set the same values at each object of `array`?

Comment: @guest271314 I am trying to loop over all of the hours, and += sum every item

Comment: Not following. Expected result `array` contains same objects?

Comment: @guest271314 They contain the same result in this example, but the result is coming from gathering up each Item value by the hour. so: records -> hours inside specific record -> hour -> 3 items in hour. sum each item according to the hour...

Comment: Is expected result at `items` array object containing, for example, `{key:134}`?

Comment: See working example if keys are known,  I need the same if keys are unkown

Comment: Still not following. Can you create a stacksnippet or jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net of working solution? Should `items` contain objects having property, value `{key:134}`? Is the issue the setting the property name of objects within `items` array to `"Item name 1"` instead of `"key"`?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hb9a3yos/ here is a working fiddle. I get the result I want, I need to get the same result but I cannot pass the Item names, they are unknown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this solves your request, but I feel there is more to it.  Are the **records** all intended to have the same **hours**?

I know it is a little dense, so I have add some comments that I hope shed some light on how this is working.

```js
const hours = [
  { "workHour" : "8", "Item name 1" : 120, "Item name 2" : 149, "Item name 3" : 137 },
  { "workHour" : "9", "Item name 1" : 134, "Item name 2" : 119, "Item name 3" : 144 },
  { "workHour" : "10", "Item name 1" : 60, "Item name 2" : 86, "Item name 3" : 83 }
];

const records = [
   { date: new Date(), statistics: hours },
   { date: new Date(), statistics: hours },
   { date: new Date(), statistics: hours }
];

// ========================
// Using map()
// For each "record" return an object based on "record"
// ========================
var result = records.map(function(record){

  // ========================
  // Create the initial result that does not depend
  // on summing up the "statistics".
  //
  // We will pass this into the reduce() and it will be the
  // initial value of the accumulator
  // ========================
  var initialResult = {date: record.date};
  // ========================
  
  // ========================
  // Using reduce()
  // itterate over the interesting work items
  // summing up the hours
  // ========================
  var finalResult = record.statistics.reduce(function(acc, item){

    Object.keys(item)  // an array of keys in our item object
          .filter(function(key){ return key !== "workHour"; }) // remove this key
          .forEach(function(key) { acc[key] = (acc[key] || 0) + item[key] }); // for each remaining key, add its value to running total

    // ========================
    // return the running total accumulator for use against the next item
    // ========================
    return acc;
    // ========================

  }, initialResult);
  // ========================

  // ========================
  // return an object based on record but with accumulated data from the reduce()
  // this object becomes an item in the array ultimately returned by map()
  // ========================
  return finalResult;
  // ========================

});
// ========================

console.log(result)
```

Here is a version without reduce:

```js
const hours = [
  { "workHour" : "8", "Item name 1" : 120, "Item name 2" : 149, "Item name 3" : 137 },
  { "workHour" : "9", "Item name 1" : 134, "Item name 2" : 119, "Item name 3" : 144 },
  { "workHour" : "10", "Item name 1" : 60, "Item name 2" : 86, "Item name 3" : 83 }
];

const records = [
   { date: new Date(), statistics: hours },
   { date: new Date(), statistics: hours },
   { date: new Date(), statistics: hours }
];

var result = records.map(function(record){
  var initialResult = {date: record.date};

  record.statistics.forEach(function(item){
    Object.keys(item)
          .filter(function(key){ return key !== "workHour"; })
          .forEach(function(key) { initialResult[key] = (initialResult[key] || 0) + item[key] });
  });

  return initialResult;
});

console.log(result)
```

Comment: @JasonBrill I noticed in a different answer you indicated that my approach was a little confusing.  I added some comments that I hope make things a little clearer.

Comment: Thank you so much! for explanation just wondering is there a way to achieve this without reduce?

Comment: I added a version that does not use reduce()

Comment: Thank you! what do you suggest to use with reduce or without?

Comment: Either is fine.  In this instance, the forEach() seems perfectly reasonable and even clearer than the reduce().  Often a reduce() can clean up a messy forEach() but in the case perhaps the reverse is true :-)

Answer (score 1):

If interpret Question correctly, you can substitute `for..of` loop for `.forEach()`, use computed property name `[key]` to set property name at object pushed to `items` array

```js
const hours = [{
  "workHour": "8",
  "Item name 1": 120,
  "Item name 2": 149,
  "Item name 3": 137
}, {
  "workHour": "9",
  "Item name 1": 134,
  "Item name 2": 119,
  "Item name 3": 144
}, {
  "workHour": "10",
  "Item name 1": 60,
  "Item name 2": 86,
  "Item name 3": 83
}, ];

const records = hours.map((hour, index) => ({
    date: new Date(),
    statistics: hours[index]
  }));

const result = {};
result.chart = [];

records.forEach((record, index) => {
  const items = [];
  for (let {statistics:hour} of [record]) {
    for (let key in hour) {
    if (key !== 'workHour') {
        items.push({
          [key]: hour[key] 
                 + (result.chart[index -1] 
                      && result.chart[index -1].hasOwnProperty("items") 
                    ? result.chart[index-1].items
                      .filter(obj => obj.hasOwnProperty(key))[0][key] 
                    : 0)          
        })
      }
    }
  };
  result.chart.push({
    date: record.date,
    items
  });
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out! JonSG has got the result I'm after but I totally don't understand his approach.. is there any simplified way of doing it?

Comment: Does `javascript` at stacksnippets not return expected result? https://jsfiddle.net/u950qf04/1/?

Comment: Almost, your items array hold additional [][] two arrays instead of directly, items -> Item 1, Item 2, Item3, like @JonSG did

Comment: Thanks.. only 1 thing left is items array need to hold record as key and inside that item key value pairs:  items: [{
    "date": "2016-11-11T21:32:47.533Z",
    "Item name 1": 314,
    "Item name 2": 354,
    "Item name 3": 364
  }] like this

Comment: by the way JonSG answer if 2x times faster in performance for () loops are very slow.. I bench marked with console.time both ooptions..

Comment: @JasonBrill Do you mean `{date, items, WorkHour:8}`?